# How can I configure a Linux backup server such that the hard drives, including the system drive, are powered off when not in use?

Tags: linux, debian, automation, cron, wake-on-lan

I'm currently working on setting up a backup server for my NAS. This server is to take an incremental backup of my NAS every 24 hours, which should only take a few minutes. Yet, I want 24/7 remote access (e.g. over SSH) to the server. This is problematic because mechanical hard drives, such as where the backups are going, tend to wear out with time that they're powered on, and this is slowed when they are powered off.

My first idea was to turn the entire computer off when not in use, and have a raspberry pi setup to do wake on lan on a fixed schedule, but this is problematic as I do not know how to schedule the backup task to run in a properly orchestrated manner, with automatic shutoff afterwards, in any reasonable way.

My next idea is to turn my hard drives off, while the rest of the system remains loaded in RAM (to facilitate SSH, cron, and whatever else I have running), where a script can automatically turn the drive on and off as needed, but my research on how todo this only comes up with information such as [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671683/how-to-turn-off-hard-drive-in-ubuntu), where some commands are given with lackluster explanation. For example, nothing in that link explains anything about keeping the system loaded in RAM while it is not in use. This technique is also problematic because the CPU and PSU fans will remain powered on.

Comment: Your premises are slightly  flawed. Turning disks on and off can be more stressful then leaving them spinning, and it is possible to power down most drives even when the PC is otherwise operational. Likewise. CPUs under clock when not working and use a fraction of the power, and CPU fans can often be spun slower when the CPU is cool (and this can be done in software and/or BIOS if supported). Shutting down a server after running a backup task is typically no harder then adding "; /sbin/shutdown -h now" to end of the command. Running on startup can be triggered from rc.local among other ways.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, turning disks on and off is likely more harmful than leaving them spinning all the time. However there are other reasons why you would want to spindown a disk that is not used most of the time (reduced power consumption is one).

You can configure automatic spindown time when the disk is not in use (or issue a forced spinup/spindown command through a script in your backup software) using [hdparm](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/hdparm/hdparm.8.en.html) (lookup the `-S` option).

Shutting down the whole system after backups can simply be done using [shutdown](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/runit-init/shutdown.8.en.html) in your backup scripts.

You can bring it up again using Wake-on-LAN as you guessed, or using tools like [rtcwake](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/util-linux/rtcwake.8.en.html) if your system supports it.